# bash: how to display the name of the first directory that contains a certain file

Tags: bash, ssh, ls, subshell

I have this:

```
ls */file
dir1/file dir2/file dir3/file
```

But I need just the first directory name, like this: `dir1`

I did this:

```
IFS="/" read foo bar <<< "$(ls */file 2>/dev/null)"
echo $foo
dir1
```

And it works, but now I have a problem with `subshell` expansion over `ssh`. Is there a more elegant way (without `subshells` or `sed`) to do this?

If not, I'll then post a question regarding a completely different issue - expanding `subshells` over `ssh`.

Comment: Perhaps you can reconsider my answer. It doesn't require a subshell.

Comment: I did (http://stackoverflow.com/a/24055011/3664780), can we make it in a single command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for F in */file; do
    D=${F%%/*}
    break
done
```

Another:

```
F=(*/file); D=${F%%/*}
```

Comment: Actually, this will give out the file names. OP wants directory. I think you meant this: `${F%%/*}` =)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ls */file | cut -d"/" -f1
```

Use `/` as a separator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tricky Double quotes!
Like so:

```
LIST=`ls */file`
echo "$LIST" | cut -d/ -f1
```

or

```
echo "$LIST" | awk -F/ {'print $1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use builtin read bulletin with `-d` option:

```
read -d '/' a < <(echo */file)
echo "$a"
dir1
```

Comment: @anubhava yeah, just wanted to edit that, but you were faster.
Ok, so this seems like the best solution, but I have a problem with subshell expansion over ssh. I tired escaping parentheses, but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Ulrik: Following command worked for me on ssh: `ssh localhost "read -d '/' a < <(echo bar/*.pdf) && echo \"$a\""`

Comment: be aware - if you're ssh-ing to localhost, you need to be in a different directory in order to see it fail. `(echo */file)` subshell is executed locally and the string is sent over ssh to read.

Comment: Did you try: `ssh localhost "read -d '/' a < <(echo bar/\*.pdf) && echo \"$a\""` command?

Comment: `cd /`

`ssh localhost "cd foo; read -d '/' a <<<(echo bar/*.pdf); echo \$a"`


and watch it fail

Comment: It will only fail if `bar` is not a sub directory in `$HOME`.

Comment: ok, it almost works, it gives me the names of all directories containing the file, I just need the name of the first one.

Comment: As I showed above `read -d '/' a < <(echo */file)` gets only part before **very first slash**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55113/discussion-between-ulrik-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the name of the folder you can use :

```
$ls -1 | awk 'NR==n'
```

Where `n=1` is the first directory, you can change the value of `n` to get the nth Directory.